# Windows share through proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, webdav

I have a Windows share and on a different subnet.  The users on the user subnet can not see the server subnet, although there is a proxy server in place on the user subnet that can.  All web traffic is sent through this proxy server (squid).

Is there any way to proxy a file share so the users can access it? I have tried an NTFS symlink, but I can't access the symlink through the share.

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 -- I had to stick with Windows because it is running a Remote Desktop Gateway as well.

Comment: The description is a bit confusing. Can you provide a network diagram? Is there a firewall involved? It could be as simple as a routing issue.

Comment: I don't think I can easily add a diagram.  Let me try to go into a little more detail, though.

Every user in our group has access to the main corporate network and the subnet they are on.

We have a subset of users that reside on a different subnet than our servers, so if they have access to the corporate network, they cannot see our groups servers.  

I have set up a proxy server that at least allows network access to our servers through the proxy (the proxy server doesn't have the subnet restriction since it doesn't access the corp network)

Comment: It sounds like you have a firewall in between the subnets; I'd start there.

Comment: No access to the firewall.  The only thing I'm allowed to change is the proxy server.

Comment: You should have someone who can access the firewall implement the change, then. We generally frown upon helping someone circumvent network security measures.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the share to WebDAV ("Web Sharing") mode, this will let Squid proxy it.